# CSS div height problem

Tags: html, css

Here is my html code

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="nav">
  </div>

  <div id="main">
  </div>
</div
```

main's height varies depending of it's content. How to get the height of nav to be the same as main's height?

Comment: What have you got so far in terms of CSS?

Answer (score 0):

theres no direct way to do this, except css3 display:table or various background hacks
google for "css 2 column layout"

**edit**
You can also use following styles

```
#container {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#nav{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
//  left right depending on your design
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no 'direct' way, btw, by javascript DOM manipulation you could get the main offsetHeight by JS

```
var main = document.getElementById('main');
var mainH = main.offsetHeight;
```

and set it to the nav element

```
var nav = document.getElementById('nav');
nav.style.height = mainH+"px";
```

Answer (score 0):

See [faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) on A List Apart